# Qual é o significado do simbolo ":" e "\\"?

Tags: shell-script

O exemplo que não entendo muito bem é:

```
cut -d : -f /etc/passwd | tr : \\t
```

O que significa os dois pontos `:` e as duas barras `\\`?

Comment: `-d :` = campos separados por : (-f falta a lista dos compos a selecionar) `tr : '\t'`substitui os ":" por tabs. `cut -d : -f 1,5 /etc/passwd | tr : '\t' para username e nome
`

Answer (score 3):

Assim como diversas linguagens de programação, ao escrever uma *String*, e existem sequencias de caracteres que retornar um valor como:

```
"\a" --> Sinal sonoro
"\n" --> Quebra de linha
"\t" --> Tabulação horizontal
```

E em *ShellScript* a barra invertida ou *Arrab* funciona igual, mas nesse caso, todo caractere que estiver depois da *Arrab* é passado para String.

```
sh ~: touch my keys # cria os arquivos my e keys
sh ~: touch my\ keys # cria o arquivo my keys
```

E quando coloca elas em sequencia `\\`, é escrito a arrab.

```
sh ~: echo escreve-ndo \\ arrab
#escrevendo \ arrab
```

Já o `:`, tem uma diferença onde é empregado, no caso do `cut -d :` está criando um delimitador para as informações que serão lançadas.

```
echo "Saida: Meu texto!!!!" > saida
cut -d : -f 1 saida
#Saida
```

Ou seja, irá escrever o conteúdo até antes do `:`.

Em `tr` o `:` representa um caractere a ser substituído.

```
echo "dados:lista" | tr : \- # dados-lista
```

Mas o `:` em alguns casos, pode ser usado para atribuir valor nulo em arquivos ou em um disco.

```
echo "dados para o arquivo" > arquivo
:>arquivo
cat arquivo
```

O conteúdo de arquivo estará vazio.